# iPhone dev mail, contacts, calendar settings

Tags: iphone, settings

I need to access a "Sort Order" and "Display Order" preferences under Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendar.

Is there any example how to do that?

Thank you
/Alex

Comment: Completely unhelpful subject.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ABPerson reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html), see `ABPersonGetSortOrdering()` and `ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat()`. You'll have to `#include <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>` and link against AddressBook.framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to change this setting.